# What is the relation between roots of classical and Atkin modular polynomial?

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Modular polynomials are a good tools in elliptic curves. I need to find the roots of $l$-th classical modular polynomial $\Phi_l(X,Y)$ over the prime field. Unfortunately the coefficients of these polynomials are so large and I haven't it. But I have an access  to Atkin modular polynomials database. Now this is my question:

> What is the relation between  roots of classical and Atkin modular polynomial over the prime field?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182168/modular-polynomials-for-elliptic-curves-point-counting